# Why aren't my class id tags working?

Tags: html, css, text, styles, text-align

Here's my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

I have two questions.

1. I can't figure out why the text in the sidebar navigation isn't black! It's blue instead.

```
#side_wrapper_text a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: right;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;

}
```

2. I want the text to align EXACTLY at the top of its box, and I can't figure out why it just doesn't do that automatically. I tried playing with line spacing options to no avail.

```
/* CONTENT ********************************************************/

.content_wrapper {
    float: left; 
    width: 980px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 45px;

}
/* Photo Box on Home Page ************************/

.home_photo { 
        display:block;
        height: 400px;
        background: rgba(0,0,255, .5);

}

/* Text Box on Home Page */

.home_text{ 
        display:block;
        float: left;
        background: rgba(255,100,255,.5);
        height: 190px;
        text-align: left;
}

/* WRITING ***************************************/

.home_writing {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(50,50,50,.5);
    height: 1000px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For problem #1, remove the space between "rgba" and the following parenthesis, i.e. `color: rgba(255,255,255,1)`.

In Chrome 25, this then made the color white, not black (to be expected). If you want black, just use `color: #000;` or `color: rbga(0,0,0,1);` if you want to specify the alpha channel for some reason.

For problem #2: The paragraph `<p>` tags have a margin of roughly 1em set by the browser's default stylesheet. Set it to zero (or some other value) to modify.

Example:

```
P { margin: 0; }
```

You might also consider using a [reset stylesheet](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) to normalize behavior across browsers and reset many of the styles set by the browser's default stylesheet.

Or at least reset all padding/margin to zero (which fixes many of the common problems):

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. BUT, I want to get all the text at the edges of the boxes as I will eventually make those garish colors white. So, I want to make sure everything is aligned. 
Seems silly to have a default; is the work around to just make the padding-top the same in every element?
Is a similar default also make the black box at the top have a white border? Thanks!

Comment: Try using a reset stylesheet (just updated my answer) which should get rid of the most common defaults. After you see how that looks, then you'll know which styles you need to set to get the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
```

to this:

```
color: #000000;
```

Comment: If the R, G, and B values each consist of the same digit repeated, you can shorten it to 3 digits. i.e. `#000000` becomes `#000`, `#ff3399` becomes `#f39`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the text color remove the space after 'rgba':

```
color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

I am not completely sure that I understand your second question but rather than playing with the line spacing.  I think that you want to change the top padding and top margin to 0 for your paragraphs.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't specify, so shouldn't they already be 0?

Comment: No(see the other answer), and because you don't specify you are leaving it up to the browser.