# rgba is not working, when i had it working 5 minutes ago

Tags: css, background-color, rgba

this is for my site http://www.blindsdetroit.com/ I need to have text that you CANNOT see through over a background image that is see through. It is not working on chrome or firefox. Also the rgb won't work either, it just says its a invalid property value? Why is this

here is my css:

```
#top_box{
background: rgba (208,206,195,.5);
position:relative;
height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Delete the space between the `rgba` and the opening parenthesis

Comment: Heh, @albertxing your comment beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just gave it a try using the [Chrome Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and it appears to be the space between `rgba` and the left parenthesis. So, instead of:

```
background: rgba (208,206,195,.5);
```

Try...

```
background: rgba(208,206,195,.5);
```

Comment: +1 - just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651209/why-arent-my-class-id-tags-working/15651270#15651270) a few hours ago. Never knew it was an issue until today.